# How does graphical model of a GP look like?

Tags: bayesian, inference, gaussian-process, graphical-model

I'm trying to understand the difference between GP and Markov process. I couldn't find answers on the internet. I figured that graphical models can tell the difference, hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Graphical model for GPR]

Here's the graphical model for GP regression, reproduced from [GPML Chapter 2](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf).

Comment: thank you! not easy to find this at all on Google!